# React Proptypes warning for a conditional rendered component

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Let's say I have 2 routes:

/app/search

/app/search/keyword

First route renders a pageSearch component with a searchBox.
Second route renders same pageSearch component with the text keyword inside and also a list of images that my ajax request should get from the api server (gallery component).

My pageSearch component will get the list of images:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.params.searchText) {
      this.props.requestPictograms(this.props.params.searchText)
    }
  }
```

However I only want to render my Gallery component if I get some data back from the server:

```
const data =  []
  render() {
   .....
    const gallery = data.length ? React.cloneElement(children, { data }) : null

    return (
      <View>
        <SearchBox />
        {gallery}
      </View>
```

The problem is that I get a warning from gallery propTypes when my route is like /app/search/keyword and I don't render gallery (no data received from the server):

```
warning.js:36Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `data` was not specified in `Gallery`.
    in Gallery (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in ScrollBehaviorContext (created by Router)
    in Router
    in MuiThemeProvider
    in IntlProvider (created by LanguageProvider)
    in LanguageProvider (created by Connect(LanguageProvider))
    in Connect(LanguageProvider)
    in Provider
```

Comment: can you give the code of the routes + both components?