# React PropTypes warning for function component with a prop that has a default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

I am using the prop-types library in a react-native project. I have a problem similar to [React prop types warning for a conditionally rendered component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101024/react-proptypes-warning-for-a-conditional-rendered-component). I have a list of custom tags that are function components, and I use a key prop to help react keep them all straight. I set the key prop to a default value which is a generated random integer converted to a string.

[EDIT] However when the custom tag is instantiated, I pass in a value which is a UUID-like number created by the backend DB: member.id.

On the first render and first render only, I get the proptypes warning:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `key` is marked as required in
> `FamilyListItem`, but its value is `undefined`.

Mind you, everything renders just fine. I'm being a bit of a nitpicker here, but I hate leaving this as is without understanding why this is happening. Below are the two functional components that are involved. I should mention that there is a parent screen which is called BabyDetailsScreen, which has a button that renders the FamilyListView or hides it. It is when this button is pressed for the first time with at least one FamilyListItem tag present, that the warning occurs. Any and all comments on how I have set this up are welcome.

[UPDATE] I decided to send the FamilyListItem tag list to the console and I found something that I think is odd. In the tag object, the key property does not show up in the props property. Perhaps I shouldn't be putting "key" in FamilyListItem.propTypes?

```
components::FamilyListView::memberTagList() - family tag list:  Array [
  Object {
    "$$typeof": Symbol(react.element),
    "_owner": FiberNode {
      "tag": 0,
      "key": null,
      "type": [Function FamilyListView],
    },
    "_store": Object {},
    "key": "2625fea9-95f6-418f-a25e-0837d1554a39",
    "props": Object {
      "familyMember": Object {
        "_deleted": null,
        "_lastChangedAt": 1632251150890,
        "_version": 9,
        "agreedCookiePolicy": null,
        "agreedDataPrivacyPolicy": null,
        "agreedTermsAndConditionsPolicy": null,
        "archived": null,
        "authUserID": "f507dafd-f8bb-4081-b2e2-5e6107cb2be1",
        "babyprofiles": Object {
          "nextToken": null,
          "startedAt": null,
        },
        "createdAt": "2021-09-17T18:28:35.388Z",
        "credentials": Object {
          "nextToken": null,
          "startedAt": null,
        },
        "firstName": "Frangelica",
        "home": Object {
          "nextToken": null,
          "startedAt": null,
        },
        "id": "2625fea9-95f6-418f-a25e-0837d1554a39",
        "lastName": "Foe",
        "licenses": Object {
          "nextToken": null,
          "startedAt": null,
        },
        "middleName": "Ffff",
        "roles": Object {
          "_deleted": null,
          "_lastChangedAt": 1631909265162,
          "_version": 10,
          "archived": null,
          "businessRole": null,
          "clinicianRole": null,
          "createdAt": "2021-09-17T18:28:35.228Z",
          "forbablioRole": null,
          "id": "a1baa1b1-8d37-405b-9340-bebc2411ae89",
          "parentGuardianRole": "PARENT",
          "updatedAt": "2021-09-17T18:28:35.228Z",
        },
        "setupComplete": true,
        "updatedAt": "2021-09-21T19:05:50.863Z",
        "work": Object {
          "nextToken": null,
          "startedAt": null,
        },
      },
      "navigable": false,
      "navigation": Object {
        "addListener": [Function addListener],
        "canGoBack": [Function canGoBack],
        "dangerouslyGetParent": [Function dangerouslyGetParent],
        "dangerouslyGetState": [Function anonymous],
        "dispatch": [Function dispatch],
        "goBack": [Function anonymous],
        "isFocused": [Function isFocused],
        "navigate": [Function anonymous],
        "pop": [Function anonymous],
        "popToTop": [Function anonymous],
        "push": [Function anonymous],
        "removeListener": [Function removeListener],
        "replace": [Function anonymous],
        "reset": [Function anonymous],
        "setOptions": [Function setOptions],
        "setParams": [Function anonymous],
      },
    },
    "ref": null,
    "type": Object {
      "$$typeof": Symbol(react.forward_ref),
      "render": [Function anonymous],
    },
  },
]
```

FamilyListView collects the family members and maps them into a list of FamilyListItems:

```js
const FamilyListView = ({
  theme = {},
  navigation = {},
  navigable = false,
  babyID = "",
}) => {
  const [familyList, setFamilyList] = React.useState([]);
  const [viewHeight, setViewHeight] = React.useState("82%");
  const safeAsync = useSafeAsync();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFamilyMembers = async () => {
      try {
        safeAsync(getBabyProfile(babyID)).then((baby) => {
          const babyUserFamily = baby.family_clinicians.items.filter((member) =>
            checkIsFamilyUser(member.user)
          );
          const family = babyUserFamily.map((babyUser) => babyUser.user);
          setFamilyList(family);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(
          "components::FamilyListView::fetchFamilyMembers() - " +
            "failed to retrieve family because: ",
          err
        );
        throw err;
      }
    };

    fetchFamilyMembers();
  }, [babyID, safeAsync]);

  const memberTagList = () => {
    let familyTags = [
      <View key={DEFAULT_LIST_KEY()}>
        <Text style={[styles.TextTr, { color: theme.colors.strong }]}>
          {"No Family Members Found!"}
        </Text>
      </View>,
    ];

    if (!isEmpty(familyList)) {
      familyTags = familyList.map((member) => (
        <FamilyListItem
          key={member.id}
          familyMember={member}
          navigation={navigation}
          navigable={navigable}
        />
      ));
      console.log(
        "components::FamilyListView::memberTagList() - num family tags: ",
        familyList.length
      );
    }

    return familyTags;
  };
  :
  :

  return (
    <View style={{ height: viewHeight }}>
      <View
        style={styles.ViewNB}
        accessible
        importantForAccessibility="auto"
        hitSlop={{}}
        pointerEvents="auto"
      >
        <View style={styles.ViewfV}>
          <IconButton
            size={32}
            icon="FontAwesome/search-plus"
            onPress={handleSearchFamily}
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={[styles.TextFL, { color: theme.colors.primary }]}>
          {`Family Members`}
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.ViewSc}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.ScrollViewl6}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator
          bounces
        >
          {memberTagList()}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

FamilyListView.propTypes = {
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  navigable: PropTypes.bool,
  babyID: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

FamilyListView::memberTagList() does all the heavy lifting in creating the list.

FamilyListItem is also a functional component, and it looks like this:

```js
const FamilyListItem = ({
  theme = {},
  navigation = {},
  familyMember = '',
  navigable = false,
  key = DEFAULT_LIST_KEY(),
}) => {
  const [memberName, setMemberName] = useState('');
  const [memberID, setMemberID] = useState('');
  const [memberRole, setMemberRole] = useState('');
  const isMounted = useIsMounted();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMember = () => {
      try {
        if (isMounted()) {
          setMemberName(`${familyMember.firstName} ${familyMember.lastName}`);
          setMemberID(familyMember.id);
          setMemberRole(
            valueFromKey(
              ParentGuardianRolesEnum,
              familyMember.roles.parentGuardianRole
            )
          );
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(
          'components::FamilyListItem::useEffect::getBaby() - fail for: ',
          err
        );
      }
    };

    fetchMember();
  }, [familyMember, isMounted]);
  :
  :

  return (
    <View style={styles.ViewPm}>
      <View
        style={[styles.View_7y, { backgroundColor: theme.colors.background }]}>
        <Touchable style={styles.Touchablem6} onPress={handleMemberDetails}>
          <View>
            <Text style={[styles.Textq5, { color: theme.colors.strong }]}>
              {memberName}
            </Text>
            <Text style={[styles.Textq4, { color: theme.colors.strong }]}>
              {memberRole}
            </Text>
            <Text style={[styles.ƒ, { color: theme.colors.strong }]}>
              {'ID: '}
              {memberID}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Touchable>
        <IconButton
          icon="FontAwesome/archive"
          size={28}
          color={theme.colors.error}
          onPress={handleArchive}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

FamilyListItem.propTypes = {
  theme: PropTypes.shape({
    colors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    typography: PropTypes.object,
    roundness: PropTypes.number,
  }).isRequired,
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({
    navigate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
  familyMember: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  navigable: PropTypes.bool,
  key: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: `key` prop has special meaning, it's not passed inside the component so prop types complain

Comment: @skyboyer - Thanks! I kind of caught that just now (didn't notice your comment) but wasn't sure about its significance.